# Print Test Result in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Currently I am making the test case repeat 2 times, so how do I print the results as 2 separate results.

I tried using the built-in function to create the text, however, it does now show either "Success" or "Failure".

Currently I have this code:

```
public class UnitTestRunner {
    static JUnitCore junitCore;
    static Class<?> testClasses;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running Junit Test Suite.");
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Successful: " + result.wasSuccessful() +
            " ran " + result.getRunCount() + " tests");
    }
}
```

This code is working correctly, but I do not know how to implement this into JUnit.

Can someone please help to show, how to implement this code into JUnit test case.

Comment: What is the desired output here?

Comment: The desired output is "Test Case Success" or "Test Case Failed: Reason for failing"

Comment: @LanYungLee What is the current output you get?

Comment: @Progman the output that i get is       "Oct 03, 2017 2:35:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1507012580237 Marionette INFO New connections will no longer be accepted
"

Comment: @LanYungLee That can't be the output when your code should at least output "Running Junit Test Suite." and the words "Sucessful", "ran" and "tests". How did you compiled your class? And how did you run this class?

Comment: It was ran as a JUnit, and the output is actually generated using the built-in function in eclipse

Comment: @LanYungLee A JUnit test class does not use the main() method. If you want to execute this method you have to compile and run this class like any other normal class with an entry point. Please rephrase your question to make it clear what you have, what you are currently getting and what you want to do instead.

Answer (score 7):

This will be slightly long answer. For the customized output you have to add your `RunListener`
You can use following sample implementation for the same.

```
public class UnitTestRunner {
    static JUnitCore junitCore;
    static Class<?> testClasses;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running Junit Test Suite.");
        junitCore = new JUnitCore();
        junitCore.addListener(new CustomExecutionListener());

        Result result = junitCore.run(TestSuite.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Successful: " + result.wasSuccessful() + " ran " + result.getRunCount() + " tests");
    }
}
```

And implementation for the `RunListener`  is as follows

```
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

public class CustomExecutionListener extends RunListener {

    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Number of tests to execute: " + description.testCount());
    }

    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Number of tests executed: " + result.getRunCount());
    }

    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting: " + description.getMethodName());
    }

    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Finished: " + description.getMethodName());
    }

    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Failed: " + failure.getDescription().getMethodName());
    }

    public void testAssumptionFailure(Failure failure) {
        System.out.println("Failed: " + failure.getDescription().getMethodName());
    }

    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Ignored: " + description.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

And by overriding the methods in `RunListener` you can format you output.

Comment: How about using it together with JUnit?

Comment: Sorry could not get your point? It is using JUNIT ? Am i missing something here?

Comment: So it is actually going to be used together with a JUnit, I want it to after running the JUnit test, to print out the informations such as: How long it took to finish the test, was the test successful, if the test failed what caused it to fail.