# How to get junit output on passed tests

Tags: java, junit

I have the following TestJunit.java file:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestJunit {

  @Test
  public void testAdd() {
    MyMath math = new MyMath(8, 10);
    assertEquals(18, math.practice());    
  }
  @Test
  public void testAdd2() {
    MyMath math = new MyMath(17, 10);
    assertEquals(18, math.practice());
  }
}
```

I only get output on the second test.  If I reverse them, I only get output on the first test.  Is there a way to get output on passed tests?

Here's my TestRunner.java file:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
  public void testRunner() {
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);

    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
      System.out.println(failure.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536753/print-test-result-in-junit

Comment: no, definitely not answered there although not a bad reference.

Comment: Regarding the other answer you just deleted: you would need a Java language parser. But honestly, have you *ever* looked at the code that fresh men put up, say here on SO? That stuff is sometimes outright crazy. I think: evaluating such input automatically, that is a **huge** task. Like solving the halting problem or so. And you know: should contain an if-statement, that is pretty easy to get in source code. And make no mistake: your smarter students might quickly learn/figure what your grading tool is doing, then people start working around it. Just saying: interesting journey ahead for you!